# How to validate filename based on a specific date range?

Tags: validation, visual-studio-2015, ssis

I have a SSIS package I am working on.  The file name is: `ap_alpha100_p1_20171013_123456.txt`

I only want the package to pick up that file if the date is within the last couple days.  For example.

`ap_alpha100_p1_20171013_123456.txt` is correct because 20171013 = 2017/10/13

`ap_alpha100_p1_20170613_123456.txt` is incorrect because 20170613 = 2017/06/13

I'm very new to SSIS and tried to google for similar issues, but my research is leaving me short.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach :

1. Create a variable `var_fileName` to store file name from for-each
   loop container.
2. Create a variable `var_flag` which will be set to
   true if date lies within this week(configurable), else false.
3. Create a for-each loop container with `ForEach file enumerator` and variable mapping set to `var_fileName`.
   [image: u1]
4. Create a `script task` within container. Read variable : var_fileName. Read-Write variable : var_flag.
5. Put up the following code in script task(C#).

   ```
           Dts.Variables["User::var_flag"].Value = false;

           String a;
           a = Dts.Variables["User::var_fileName"].Value.ToString();   //output: ap_alpha100_p1_20171010_123456
           String b;
           b = a.Substring(15, 8);  //output: 20171010


           string result = DateTime.ParseExact(b, "yyyyMMdd",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");   //output: 2017-10-10

           DateTime oDate = Convert.ToDateTime(result);    //convert string to datetime
           DateTime Today = DateTime.Today;
           DateTime StartDate = Today.AddDays(-((int)Today.DayOfWeek));
           DateTime EndDate = StartDate.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1);

           if (oDate > StartDate && oDate < EndDate)
           {
               Dts.Variables["User::var_flag"].Value = true;
           }
           else
           {
               Dts.Variables["User::var_flag"].Value = false;
           }
   ```

It should look like this(comments shown for easy understanding):

[image: i2]

6. Now simply use a constraint between `script task` and `Data Flow Task`with constraint condition `@[User::var_flag] == TRUE`.

Logic is: If the date is in-between this week, then flag is turned to true, else false. On true condition, the Data flow task executes.